# Record won't update MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the below will not update the record. It gives me a success message but does not actually update the record. I have gone through tons off revisions and tried everything I can think of. Can anyone else see where the issue is?

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $company = $_POST['company'];
        $rep1 = $_POST['rep1'];
        $rep2 = $_POST['rep2'];
        $rep3 = $_POST['rep3'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $fax = $_POST['fax'];
        $cell = $_POST['cell'];
        $service = $_POST['service'];
        $license = $_POST['license'];
        $expdate = $_POST['expdate'];
        $active = $_POST['active'];
        $userlevel = $_POST['userlevel'];

$host="XXXXXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXXXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXXXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect"); 


// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET id='".$id."', fname='".$fname."', lname='".$lname."', email='".$email."', company='".$company."', rep1='".$rep1."', rep2='".$rep2."', rep3='".$rep3."', phone='".$phone."', fax='".$fax."', cell='".$cell."', service='".$service."', license='".$license."', expdate='".$expdate."', active='".$active."', userlevel='".$userlevel."'".
       "WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
  $emailID = "info@domain.com";
        $subject = "Registration notification from. $fname . through website";
$body = <<<EOD

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Name: </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$fname $lname</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Mobile: </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Email: </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$email</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">License Number: </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$license</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

EOD;

        $headers = "From: info@domain.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

        mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers );
        echo "<h4>Thank you for updating your account info. We will authorize your account and notify you once we have verified your license number and expiration.</h4>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: why would you update the `id`? plus, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: never output a fixed (and USELESS) error message like "Error" when you could get told about what the problem actually is.  `echo mysqli_error($con)` would have saved you a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last value doesn't have a whitespace after it, so the `where` keyword is "stuck" to it.
Just add a space before the `where` and you should be OK:

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET id='".$id."', fname='".$fname."', lname='".$lname."', email='".$email."', company='".$company."', rep1='".$rep1."', rep2='".$rep2."', rep3='".$rep3."', phone='".$phone."', fax='".$fax."', cell='".$cell."', service='".$service."', license='".$license."', expdate='".$expdate."', active='".$active."', userlevel='".$userlevel."'".
   " WHERE id = '".$id."'"; // Note the additional space here
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is general: a mess of periods and extra quotes means you can't see litle things like the space you needed in the query. Also you don't have a mysql error generated on query fail, that would have helped.

Other problems: you're typing too much. Why make variables for each post value that have the same name as the key when you can just construct your query? Also you need to escape your values.

Here's my take:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect"); 

$id=mysql_real_escape_string($id);
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
//exclude id
if($k!='id'){
//escape values
$escaped_value= mysql_real_escape_string($v);
//set up array for update query
$query_parts[]="$k='$escaped_value'";
//create variables with the same name as the key
${$k}=$v;
}
}

$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET ".implode(",",$query_parts)." $WHERE id = '$id' ";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
```